# php check matched time range with current time within an array

Tags: php, arrays, date, multidimensional-array

I have a array with time ranges, 
the time range has specific video,
i m going to show video which matched with current time

**i created a variables like below, and assigned to array,
anyone please help me for filter video for current time from array**

**ex- if the server time is  2012-06-08 14:45:10 this i need show video 2**

```
$d1 = "2012-06-08 14:26:39";
$video1='http://video-js.zencoder.com/oceans-clip.mp4';
$d2 = "2012-06-08 14:39:39";
$video2='http://video-js.zencoder.com/oceans-clip.mp4';
$d3 = "2012-06-08 14:56:10";

$cc=array(
1=>array($d,$d2,$video1),
2=>array($d2,$d3,$video2)
);

//get current time
$ctime=date('Y-m-d H:i:s',time());
//need to check matched array element for current time within above array date ranges
//Ex - if the server time is  2012-06-08 14:45:10 this need show video 2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this

```
$showvideo = "";
for ($i = 1; $i <= sizeof($cc); $i++) {
    $video = $cc[$i];
    if ($ctime >= $video[0] && $ctime <= $video[1]) {
        $showvideo = $video[2];
        break;
    }
}

if ($showvideo == "") {
    // Error
}
```

Basically PHP allows you to compare dates so just go through array and compare each to see if the date you has is between the two.

Comment: Er excuse my use of foreach, I think I used it wrong, let me correct it, I'm really rusty on PHP and code in Python these days.

Comment: Haha yeah sorry :( I really forgot PHP syntax o.o But glad the logic got through :) Cheers [Edit: Okay now I think I corrected the syntax to work with what you presented XD Sorry about that haha]

Answer (score 1):

Your going to need to assign each video to have a range of time, and then you can look for the correct video based on your time input

for example

```
$ctime=date('Y-m-d H:i:s',time());

$video1=array("http://video-js.zencoder.com/oceans-clip.mp4","2012-06-08 14:26:39","2012-06-08 14:39:39")

if ($ctime >= $video1[2]) && ($ctime <= $video1[3]) { echo $video1[1]; }
```

I believe this should solve your problem